# Mailing content to a list/group of email addresses

Tags: views, 7, taxonomy-terms, nodes, emails

What kind of module should I use to send content to a list of emails?

- I need to create a groups with list of emails.
- I need to send it to one or a few of these groups.
- I need for admins to be able to look at the email addresses which will receive the emails.

I am thinking about using mailchimp, but it does not fulfill all of my needs. Also simplenews_roles can be a good decision, but whre is no version on drupal-7. Is there another option available?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Newsletter](http://drupal.org/project/newsletter) module, which has a release for Drupal 7.

> Newsletter module aims to be a full blown newsletter solution for Drupal 7. It is especially recommended for people that need more than one newsletter list for their site.
>
> #### Features
>
> - **Multiple newsletters lists** configurable on existing terms
> - Plain text or HTML out of the box.
> - **Multiple schedules** Each newsletter can have more than one schedule, e.g. Daily, Monthly, Weekly, manually or even custom, eg after 10 new posts for this term.
> - **Centralized administration and configuration** on a single page.
> - Users can **customize** the terms in the list they subscribe to.
> - Custom template per list.
> - **Statistics** (CTR and Open-Rate).
> - Drupal 7 only.

Comment: Its not the best solution for me, because i need send content manualy to list of people.

Comment: This can handle manual newsletters as well.