# How to email all group members after a new node is added when using the Group module?

Tags: 7, users, emails, group

I have created one group using the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module. In that group I have 1 node type and 3 members.

I want to send a confirmation email to group members whenever I add new nodes of that node type. How can I do that?

**Notes**:

- My question here is different from the question about "[Mailing content to a list/group of email addresses](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/16855/mailing-content-to-a-list-group-of-email-addresses)" (mine is specific to the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module).
- I have not (yet) tried using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module for this, since I don't know how to integrate the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module with the Rules module.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mailing content to a list/group of email addresses](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/16855/mailing-content-to-a-list-group-of-email-addresses)

Comment: @Mołot : this question is related to the "group" module, so IMHO not a duplicate as you suggested in your comment above. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Molot my question is different

Answer (score 3):

## Only using the Groups module

The [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module is an upcoming alternative for the [Organic Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) module for D7, for which right now there is only a beta version available.
**Remark**: the [Groups, Communities and Co](https://www.drupal.org/project/gcc) module (= GCC) is yet another alternative (with an official release for D7).

The Group module appears to be an interesting alternative, though it doesn't come with a lot (if any) documentation so far.

The best docu available, I think, is to read its sources. In doing so, I learned that its [Group Invite](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/group/tree/modules/ginvite/ginvite.info) submodule "*Allows **group members** to invite people into their group*", which will trigger appropriate eMails. Of course, that implies that the user who wants to send these invites, is already a group member. But this "function" is not really what you seem to be looking for (as per your additional comment to my answer here).

Instead, you want to "Send an email to group members of particular group when a new node is created". To do so, I'd narrow down your question to 3 sub-questions (= tasks), and try to implement this using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module, as further detailed below ...

## Also using the Rules module

#### Rules Event

That's easy, more or less out-of-the-Rule-box: ***When a new node is created***.

#### Rules Condition

This is your **Challenge 1**: Only if "Node type of the created node belongs to some group".

#### Rules Action

Create a Rules "component" to send an eMail (anybody can do that, right?). Here is a typical sample of such component (in Rules export format, just import it in your own environment via copy-paste):

```
{ "rules_send_email_notification" : {
    "LABEL" : "Send eMail notification",
    "PLUGIN" : "action set",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "USES VARIABLES" : { "user_to_notify" : { "label" : "User to be notified", "type" : "user" } },
    "ACTION SET" : [
      { "mail" : {
          "to" : [ "user-to-notify:mail" ],
          "subject" : "New node was added",
          "message" : "New node was added for content type ...",
          "from" : "[site:mail]",
          "language" : [ "" ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Obviously, the ***Subject*** and ***Content*** of the eMail may need review / tuning, while you might also want to use some other ***From*** eMail ID.

This is your **Challenge 2**:  construct the "To" content of such eMail, i.e. all eMail IDs of all members of the group. That is what the value should be for `user-to-notify:mail` in the Rules component shown above.

## Write your custom Rule(s)

To address the above **Challenges 1 and 2**, you could write your custom module, in which you basically would do 2 things:

- Take advantage of the [very well documented API](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/group/tree/group.api.php) provided by the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module.
- Write your own custom Rules, similar to what's explained in the great tutorial [Drupal custom Rules how to write your own events conditions, actions and custom object (+ custom tokens)](http://dominiquedecooman.com/blog/drupal-custom-rules-how-write-your-own-events-conditions-actions-and-custom-object-custom-token).

If you're looking for more Rules related coding samples, you may want to look at the [Rules URL Argument](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_url_argument) module. Here is a quote about it (from its project page, bold markup added here):

> ... provides two rules **conditions** based on URL arguments:
>
> - check if a URL argument is present.
> - compare the value of an URL argument.
>
> It also provides an **action** that makes the value of an URL argument available as new variable to Rules.

The newly provided Rules actions and conditions can be found under the "URL Argument" conditions and actions groups in the rule configuration interface.

For an example of how to use it, refer to [Comment # 3 in issue # 1686360](https://www.drupal.org/node/1686360#comment-6306112) which is about "*Pass an amount to the url, ie; site/content/node-title?amount=10 or /node-title?=amount:10*".

Comment: how can i send email to group members of particular group on creation of new node ?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Thank you for this tutorial. But I can not create my rule. I wish that when a group is flag, an email is sent to all members of that group. How to do this ?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I just post a new question. thank you in advance for your help http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/219263/send-mail-to-members-of-the-group-when-the-group-is-flaging

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I deleted the last sentence. But I do not understand (with "poorly").

Comment: @Mathieu, ok, merci for that. FYI: to me that phrase looked like "the integration of Group with rules, views, and permissions is terrible". That's probably (hopefully!) NOT what you wanted to say/write. If you want, add an extra comment here to better explain what you wanted to say in that phrase. I'll then try to help you to find a better description for it, ok? PS: maybe something like "*I find it difficult to understand how Group integrates with rules, views and permissions*"?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I think the rules do not fit well the conditions of Module "Group" and that the views did not manage permissions of the modules (if I compare with organic group). I also have a second question http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/219277/add-the-column-to-the-list-of-group-members

Comment: @Mathieu ok, now I think I start to understand what you mean with that "poorly". For views and permission there is some Group issue that explains some issue about it, and the 2 possible solutions for it (don't recall it without looking it up, I may come back to that later on). And for Rules Conditions there are no (or not many)  Group related ones, except the standard ones that you get for any "entity", right? But that's also because Group is all entity based, and you should consider Group as a lego-box where "you" put the pieces together yourself (via integrations with other modules).

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens yes, that's exactly it. It also lacks the integration of the token with the rules.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I'd be interested to know what approaches are valid for the Drupal 8 version of Group? Especially since Rules is not yet ready. See https://www.drupal.org/project/group/issues/2989112

Answer (score 1):

Install and enable [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module. Now you can see there is a already created inactive rule at admin/config/workflow/rules path. Just enable this rule and you are done.

Comment: thanx for your comment. I tried that also, but this is not a solution for my issue

Comment: @SonvirChoudhary, Sorry my fault, above solution will work for Oraganic Groups module.